# Play 2: How can I get an URL with parameters that aren't encoded when reverse routing?

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0, url-encoding

This my route:

```
GET /login controllers.Auth.login(from: String ?= null)
```

So, when I do this:

```
public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Context context) {
    return redirect(controllers.routes.Auth.login(context.request().uri()));
}
```

I get:

```
mydomain.com/login?from=%2Fmy%2Fpage
```

But I want the URL to look like this:

```
mydomain.com/login?from=/my/page
```

I can obtain this nice url, readable by anyone, doing this:

```
public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Context context) {
    return redirect(controllers.routes.Auth.login().url() + "?from=" + context.request().uri());
}
```

With the route:

```
GET /login controllers.Auth.login()
```

But that's wrong.

Can someone tell me if it is doable? Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it - slash has its usage even in the param, therefore it SHOULD be encoded.

Also for security reasons that isn't best option.

On the other hand, in Play you have other possibilities to pass the return URL, my favorite are Flash/Session scopes and/or in mem Cache API. If you're interested in details, let me know, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Well, I thought of using the flash scope (and actually wrote the code), but I like the idea that the user can see the information (`/login?next=/mypage` is meaningful). Still, I'd like to see your solution. Thank you.